# How to redirect all Laravel routes to a new subdomain by using laravel route system?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Redirect all Laravel route to the same route but change base URL.

I want to transfer Laravel project from domain to subdomain
What is the best way to redirect all request on the last domain to the same new subdomain.

for example if user send request to this URL

```
mydomain.com/page/1
```

redirect to this URL

```
subdomain.mydomain.com/page/1
```

I prefer to handle inside laravel project. not NGINX config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this at the Laravel level, you can use a Middleware. Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for inspecting and filtering HTTP requests entering your application.

Here is an example of how you might do it.

First, create a new Middleware by running the command:

```
php artisan make:middleware SubdomainRedirectMiddleware
```

Next, open the newly created file app/Http/Middleware/SubdomainRedirectMiddleware.php and add the redirection logic into the handle method:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    // Replace 'mydomain' with your actual domain
    if ($request->getHost() === 'mydomain.com') {

        // Replace 'subdomain' with your actual subdomain
        return redirect()->to(str_replace('mydomain.com', 'subdomain.mydomain.com', $request->fullUrl()));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then, you need to register this middleware. Open app/Http/Kernel.php, add the following line to the routeMiddleware array:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'subdomain.redirect' => \App\Http\Middleware\SubdomainRedirectMiddleware::class,
];

Route::group(['middleware' => 'subdomain.redirect'], function () {
    // All your routes go here
});

Please replace 'mydomain' and 'subdomain' with your actual domain and subdomain in SubdomainRedirectMiddleware.php.
```

▽Here is a Reference
https://www.w3schools.in/laravel/middleware